Calculate pct_change() for a column based on last value of 2 different columns
I am trying to calculate the price change for stock price in a dataframe that contains Entry and Exit signals in separate columns and want to get the PnL only for the range between these 2.
Date       Price    Entry Signal    Exit Signal   Price Change
2024-01-18  3595.0  NaN            NaN
2024-01-19  3280.0  Entry          NaN
2024-01-22  3505.0  NaN            NaN
2024-01-23  3945.0  NaN            Exit       (3945 / 3280- 1)
2024-01-24  4075.0  NaN            NaN
2024-03-07  10270.0 Entry          NaN
2024-03-08  8120.0  NaN            nan
2024-03-11  6620.0  NaN            Exit       (6620 / 10270 - 1)

So far I am relying on a for loop looping through every row and have a variable called position where I increment by 1 (once Entry is triggered) and reset to 0 (once Exit is triggered) but there must be a smarter/faster way givne this is a dataframe.

Code
If entries and exits alternate, you can filter out rows that don't contain entries and exits, and then get pct_change.
# condition to filter rows excluding Entry and Exit.
cond = df[['Entry Signal', 'Exit Signal']].notna().any(axis=1)

# After filtering, get pct_change & make "Price change" column
df['Price Change'] = (
    df.loc[cond, 'Price']
      .pct_change()
      .where(df['Exit Signal'].notna())
)

df:
         Date    Price Entry Signal Exit Signal  Price Change
0  2024-01-18   3595.0         None        None           NaN
1  2024-01-19   3280.0        Entry        None           NaN
2  2024-01-22   3505.0         None        None           NaN
3  2024-01-23   3945.0         None        Exit      0.202744
4  2024-01-24   4075.0         None        None           NaN
5  2024-03-07  10270.0        Entry        None           NaN
6  2024-03-08   8120.0         None        None           NaN
7  2024-03-11   6620.0         None        Exit     -0.355404

Example Code
This is the code that generates your sample, so check it out as an example.
import pandas as pd
data = {"Date": ["2024-01-18", "2024-01-19", "2024-01-22", "2024-01-23", "2024-01-24", "2024-03-07", "2024-03-08", "2024-03-11"], "Price": [3595.0, 3280.0, 3505.0, 3945.0, 4075.0, 10270.0, 8120.0, 6620.0], "Entry Signal": [None, "Entry", None, None, None, "Entry", None, None], "Exit Signal": [None, None, None, "Exit", None, None, None, "Exit"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


That's a nice an concise approach! Just one remark, if Entry/Exit are not strictly alternating,  this would compute the pct_change between successive Entry/Exit ;)

Thats the thing this is useful but I have lines where there maybe 2 Entry before the Exit meaning I don't want to count the second entry (only the first entry after last exit)

IIUC, you can mask Price based on each flag, ffill the Entry, and compute the percentage change:
df['Price Change'] = (df['Price'].div(df['Price'].where(df['Entry Signal'].notna()).ffill())
                      .sub(1).where(df['Exit Signal'].notna())
                     )

Output:
         Date    Price Entry Signal Exit Signal  Price Change
0  2024-01-18   3595.0          NaN         NaN           NaN
1  2024-01-19   3280.0        Entry         NaN           NaN
2  2024-01-22   3505.0          NaN         NaN           NaN
3  2024-01-23   3945.0          NaN        Exit      0.202744
4  2024-01-24   4075.0          NaN         NaN           NaN
5  2024-03-07  10270.0        Entry         NaN           NaN
6  2024-03-08   8120.0          NaN         NaN           NaN
7  2024-03-11   6620.0          NaN        Exit     -0.355404


Pure Numpy :
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


data = {
    'Date': pd.to_datetime(['2024-01-18', '2024-01-19', '2024-01-22', '2024-01-23', 
                            '2024-01-24', '2024-03-07', '2024-03-08', '2024-03-11']),
    'Price': [3595.0, 3280.0, 3505.0, 3945.0, 4075.0, 10270.0, 8120.0, 6620.0],
    'Entry Signal': [np.nan, 'Entry', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 'Entry', np.nan, np.nan],
    'Exit Signal': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 'Exit', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 'Exit']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


df['Entry_Price'] = np.where(df['Entry Signal'] == 'Entry', df['Price'], np.nan)
df['Exit_Price']  = np.where(df['Exit Signal']  == 'Exit',  df['Price'], np.nan)

df['Entry_Price'] = df['Entry_Price'].ffill()

# Vectorized calculation of PnL
df['Price Change'] = np.where(df['Exit Signal'] == 'Exit',
                               (df['Exit_Price'] / df['Entry_Price']) - 1, np.nan)

# Drop the helper columns for cleaner output
#df = df.drop(columns=['Entry_Price', 'Exit_Price'])

print(df.to_string())
'''
       Date    Price Entry Signal Exit Signal  Entry_Price  Exit_Price  Price Change
0 2024-01-18   3595.0          NaN         NaN          NaN         NaN           NaN
1 2024-01-19   3280.0        Entry         NaN       3280.0         NaN           NaN
2 2024-01-22   3505.0          NaN         NaN       3280.0         NaN           NaN
3 2024-01-23   3945.0          NaN        Exit       3280.0      3945.0      0.202744
4 2024-01-24   4075.0          NaN         NaN       3280.0         NaN           NaN
5 2024-03-07  10270.0        Entry         NaN      10270.0         NaN           NaN
6 2024-03-08   8120.0          NaN         NaN      10270.0         NaN           NaN
7 2024-03-11   6620.0          NaN        Exit      10270.0      6620.0     -0.355404
'''

Using Polars :
import polars as pl


data = {
    'Date': ['2024-01-18', '2024-01-19', '2024-01-22', '2024-01-23', 
             '2024-01-24', '2024-03-07', '2024-03-08', '2024-03-11'],
    'Price': [3595.0, 3280.0, 3505.0, 3945.0, 4075.0, 10270.0, 8120.0, 6620.0],
    'Entry Signal': [None, 'Entry', None, None, None, 'Entry', None, None],
    'Exit Signal': [None, None, None, 'Exit', None, None, None, 'Exit']
}

df = pl.DataFrame(data)

# Forward fill Entry_Price
df = df.with_columns(
    pl.when(pl.col("Entry Signal") == "Entry").then(pl.col("Price"))
    .otherwise(None).fill_null(strategy="forward").alias("Entry_Price")
)

# Calculate the Price Change for Exit signals
df = df.with_columns(
    pl.when(pl.col("Exit Signal") == "Exit").then((pl.col("Price") / pl.col("Entry_Price")) - 1)
    .otherwise(None).alias("Price Change")
)

print(df)
'''
shape: (8, 6)
┌────────────┬─────────┬──────────────┬─────────────┬─────────────┬──────────────┐
│ Date       ┆ Price   ┆ Entry Signal ┆ Exit Signal ┆ Entry_Price ┆ Price Change │
│ ---        ┆ ---     ┆ ---          ┆ ---         ┆ ---         ┆ ---          │
│ str        ┆ f64     ┆ str          ┆ str         ┆ f64         ┆ f64          │
╞════════════╪═════════╪══════════════╪═════════════╪═════════════╪══════════════╡
│ 2024-01-18 ┆ 3595.0  ┆ null         ┆ null        ┆ null        ┆ null         │
│ 2024-01-19 ┆ 3280.0  ┆ Entry        ┆ null        ┆ 3280.0      ┆ null         │
│ 2024-01-22 ┆ 3505.0  ┆ null         ┆ null        ┆ 3280.0      ┆ null         │
│ 2024-01-23 ┆ 3945.0  ┆ null         ┆ Exit        ┆ 3280.0      ┆ 0.202744     │
│ 2024-01-24 ┆ 4075.0  ┆ null         ┆ null        ┆ 3280.0      ┆ null         │
│ 2024-03-07 ┆ 10270.0 ┆ Entry        ┆ null        ┆ 10270.0     ┆ null         │
│ 2024-03-08 ┆ 8120.0  ┆ null         ┆ null        ┆ 10270.0     ┆ null         │
│ 2024-03-11 ┆ 6620.0  ┆ null         ┆ Exit        ┆ 10270.0     ┆ -0.355404    │
└────────────┴─────────┴──────────────┴─────────────┴─────────────┴──────────────┘

'''

